# How to know a call back method execution ended 

Tags: visual-c++

I my using a VC++ DLL from our C# Application .
In DLL there is a method that invoked a call back method....
Before call back method execution end...control comes in the C# progarm....
MY 1 Question is  it ok?

But i need a method call from our C# Application after Call back method executed success fully
in DLL.

MY 2 Question is how to know that called Call back Method is success fully executed ???

I am trying with the help of A a Variable keeping  inside the call back method by assign, value "1" and in our C# application using while loop checking the value of that Variable 
for 1.After that i put the C# Method.....

BUT THIS Approach is not working fine

Comment: In it's current form, it's hardly possible to provide a meaningful answer to your question. Please revise it.

Answer (score 0):

It all sounds a bit too messy, but I don't really know what you're try to achieve so, I can't tell you it "it is ok".

Here's an idea for your 2nd question:
The method in c++ that is being called from c# can call the method that invokes the callback, and than WaitForSingleObject() waiting for an even to be called (create an Event handle using CreateEvent()).

The call back function can do whatever it is doing, and at the end, you can SetEvent() to the event the original thread is waiting for.
The SetEvent() will release the original thread.

**Make sure you always SetEvent() in the callback function, or your thread will get stuck!**

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for synchronization functions.

Good Luck!